# Spring Project to refer classes from OSGi jars

Tags: spring, osgi

I am currently writing a Spring Console Application , which needs to refer to jars that are build using the OSGi, How do I Initialize a class implementing an interface from this jar in my Spring Project.

The Class in the OSGi is EmployeeService (Interface) and EmployeeImpl (Implementation)

I have tried two things listed below the first one as obvious gives me a null pointer Exception and second one gives compliation error stating that there are no public constructor defined

Soution 1

```
@Component
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

private EmployeeService employeeService;
public List<String> getData(){
List<String> employeeService.getEmployees();

}
```

}

Solution 2

```
@Component
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {


public List<String> getData(){
EmployeeImpl employee=new EmployeeImpl;
List<String> employeeService.getEmployees();

} 


}
```

Comment: Please state clearly:  1. what you are trying to do; 2. what you have tried (the above code samples are completely insufficient... one of them isn't even proper Java); 3. what the results were; 4. how those results differ from your expectation.

Comment: The code is in java , it uses Spring anotations

Comment: You may think that the code is in Java, but the Java compiler disagrees with you.